# Excel formulas're not working while changing data on xml

Tags: php, xml, excel

I have an Excel template: `test.xlsx` with 2 sheet:

Sheet1: formula on cell B2: `=Sheet2!$D$4`

Sheet2: I put on cell D4 value: `data`

It load normally with Sheet1 cell B2 value is `data`, Sheet2 cell D4 value is `data`

But when I close file and change extension `.xlsx` to `.zip`, extract zip, and change Sheet2 cell D4 on `xl\worksheets\sheet2.xml` or `xl\sharedStrings.xml` and zip file, change to extension `.xlsx` again, cell B2 on Sheet1 not change without I double click on cell B2 Sheet1 and enter, or change value of Sheet2 cell D4

The formula is not applied when I changed data on `xl\worksheets\sheet2.xml` or `xl\sharedStrings.xml`

HOWEVER, when I open file with Excel 365, the formula works well

Any body knows this? Help me.

Thank you

Comment: What exactly has this to do with `php`?

Comment: @Mark Baker: I use php to unzip and change data of xml file

Comment: Not mentioned anywhere in your question; and no code shown, so we can't see whether it's doing what it's supposed to be doing

Comment: I'm doing this without running program, as my description

I just do it manually, but it's not work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Automatic Calculation Selected.

> Go to Formulas-->Calculation-->Calculation Options and select "Automatic".